# How to shift in Vivaldi Fully Loaded

Tags: switch-statement, vivaldi

I am using "Vivaldi Classic" mode that was chosen at the welcome screen. How do I switch to "Vivaldi Fully Loaded"?

I expect that I can switch between "Vivaldi Essential", "Vivaldi Classic", and "Vivaldi Fully Loaded" from the settings, but in the settings there is no option for "Vivaldi Classic", "Vivaldi Essential", or "Vivaldi Fully Loaded".

How do I switch between them?

Answer (score 0):

Simply open a tab in Vivaldi and go to (paste into the URL field):

```
vivaldi://welcome
```

This will allow you to switch between the available options.

[image: Vivaldi options]

Click *Finish* when done.

Comment: thank you but now i shifted in brave browser thank you for the message

Comment: For future questions you might ask, @TombTab, please consider looking at answers a bit quicker than 4 months later. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

These are just marketing terms; they are not in the settings. The only difference between "Vivaldi Classic" and "Vivaldi Fully Loaded" is enabling the in-browser mail client (See image). It includes Mail, Feeds, and Calendar. The welcome screen is only for new users or if you create a new profile (icon in top right of toolbar).

It's just one tick: **Go to Settings, Mail, and tick the check box**.

**Vivaldi settings Enable Mail**

[image]